# snprintf проверить успешность

Tags: c

В man функции snprinf написано, что

> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.

Нужно ли в дополнение делать тест на то, что было написано больше,чем размер массива?

Answer (score 0):

Эта функция никогда не должна записывать больше, чем размер массива. Одна в случае, когда размер массива недостаточен, то возвращается количество символов, которое было бы записано в массив (за исключением завершающего нуля), если бы в нем было достаточно места. Так что проверять нужно обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве реализаций libc `snprinf` почти никогда не завершается с отрицательным кодом возврата. Фактически, единственная ошибка, которая может к этому привести (и возвращается в `errno`) — `ENOMEM` (во многих реализациях он может использовать `malloc()`). Паранойи ради, на это, конечно, стоит проверять. Но спокойно можно отделаться и простым `assert`'ом.

> Нужно ли в дополнение делать тест на то, что было написано больше,чем размер массива?

А вот тест на то что размера буфера хватило крайне желателен. Как известно, при успешном завершении `snprinf` возвращает размер буфера, который *понадобился бы* для того, чтобы записать всю строку.